# How to ensure CodeDeploy keeps all auto-scaling group instances in maintenance while purging cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I am working on a deployment process involving the following:

- Gitlab runner pushes a Magento 1.9 app to a S3 bucket
- Gitlab runner deploys the app using CodeDeploy
- CodeDeploy deploys the application on all instances that are up in the auto-scaling group

The issue with this is that CodeDeploy events do not necessarily happen at the exact same second and that might cause issues with the way we reload the application cache.

Our application should clear the cache only when all active instances are in maintenance to avoid getting new http requests (otherwise it might throw a "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations" exception).

We thought of using lock files on a shared folder across all instances but that sounds very old-school.

Any idea on how to ensure all instances are in maintenance for the clear cache to happen would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Magento, but it sounds like there are a few things that need to happen:

**1. Put instances into maintenance mode**

Inside of your `appspec`, you presumably use the `ApplicationStop` lifecycle hook or another hook to put an individual instance into maintenance mode.

**2. Wait for all instances to go into maintenance mode and purge cache**

Assuming you put the hosts into maintenance mode in `ApplicationStop`, you could use another [lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) to wait for all instances to go into maintenance mode. For example, you could have a script in `BeforeInstall` that checks if all instances got past `ApplicationStop` and starts the purge if they did (i.e. it's the last one).

Here's some pseudocode:

```
# BeforeInstall or something other hook script

# 1. Get the instance details from CodeDeploy
instances = listDeploymentInstances().map(instanceId -> getDeploymentInstance(instanceId))

# 2. Check if all of the instances have completed ApplicationStop
for instance in instances {
  applicationStopStatus = instance.instanceSummary.lifecycleEvents
    .findFirst(event -> event.lifecycleEventName == "ApplicationStop")
    .status

  # If it's succeeded, we're good to go
  if status == "Succeeded
    purgeCache()
  # If it's failed, you'll have to decide what should be done
  else if status == "Failed"
    # Abort the deployment or handle some other way
  # If it's not completed, ignore it and let another instance kick off the purge
  else
    return
}
```

**3. Wait for purge to complete and exit maintenance mode**

Using a different lifecycle hook, probably `ApplicationStart` or `ValidateService`, wait for your purge to complete and exit maintenance mode. As long as the purge takes less than 1 hour, your instances shouldn't time out the lifecycle hooks.

If you wanted to do this via CodeDeploy, I'd do something like the above. Of course, you could manage this outside of the deployment and have some sort of code running on your instances that manages all of that.